# How can I call a layout after clicking a button?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am having a difficulty displaying a layout. Here is my intention: 
1. User clicks Button
2. A message pops up and user selects between Yes or No
3. When yes is clicked a layout named "dialpad" will be displayed.

But when I click "yes" it says "Unfortunately,  has stopped." Can anyone help me ?
I do know there's a problem on this line...

```
ViewStub stub = (ViewStub)findViewById(R.id.dialpad);
stub.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Thank you for your help !

Here's the code:

`package com.example;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewStub;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class ExampleGUIDialogActivity extends Activity {

    final Context context = this;
    private Button button;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAlert);

        // add button listener
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        context);

                // set title
                alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Your Title");

                // set dialog message
                alertDialogBuilder
                .setMessage("Click yes to exit!")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        // if this button is clicked, close
                        // current activity
                        // launch dialer
                        ViewStub stub = (ViewStub)findViewById(R.id.dialpad);
                        stub.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        //stub.inflate();
                        //View mDialerView = (View)findViewById(R.id.dtmf_twelve_key_dialer_view);
                        //mDialerView.bringToFront();


                        ExampleGUIDialogActivity.this.finish();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        // if this button is clicked, just close
                        // the dialog box and do nothing
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

                // create alert dialog
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                // show it
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        });
    }


}`

Comment: Can you please post some code? What is the error specifically?

Comment: It will be very difficult to help you without seeing any code. Don't you think so?

Comment: remove this line `ExampleGUIDialogActivity.this.finish();`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ViewStub stub = (ViewStub)findViewById(R.id.dialpad);
if (stub != null){
    stub.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Can you provide any logcat info???

Answer (score 0):

Well, one problem is that you're inflating the `ViewStub` and then immediately exiting your Activity, which will cause all kinds of problems; first among them, your user will never see the new layout!

I think you may want to launch a new `Activity` which has as its content view the layout you're trying to inflate, and allow the user to perform some action based on it... or perhaps you want to call `dialog.dismiss()` instead?

Comment: I removed the ExampleGuiDialogActivity.this.finish() and tried try catch around setVisibility and the application didn't crash, but didn't show the layout.